# interpreting parameter estimates of lme4 (three factor modeling)

Tags: mixed-model

I am beginner in using the linear mixed-effect model (lme4). I tried the following to fit three factors (fixed effect)and one factor (farm) as random. I got the output but failed to interpret it specially the estimates. Can you help? for what parameters the estimates belongs?

fit1 <- lmer(GY ~ fert*seas*den+(1|farm) ,  data = cr)

> summary(fit1)
> Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method [
> lmerModLmerTest]
> Formula: GY ~ fert * seas * den + (1 | farm)
> Data: cr

REML criterion at convergence: 407.9

Scaled residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-1.8708 -0.7313 -0.2015  0.5301  2.9092

Random effects:
Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
farm     (Intercept) 0.135    0.3674
Residual             1.595    1.2628
Number of obs: 126, groups:  farm, 3

### Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error       df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                   4.4256     0.4360  20.2216  10.149  2.2e-09 ***
fertRDFU                      0.4909     0.5385 112.0677   0.912  0.36390
fertWOF                      -0.8364     0.5385 112.0677  -1.553  0.12319
seas2018                     -1.6264     0.5531 112.3667  -2.941  0.00398 **
den53,333                     1.6909     0.5385 112.0677   3.140  0.00216 **
fertRDFU:seas2018            -0.8209     0.7803 112.0677  -1.052  0.29506
fertWOF:seas2018             -0.3336     0.7803 112.0677  -0.428  0.66979
fertRDFU:den53,333           -0.2273     0.7615 112.0677  -0.298  0.76591
fertWOF:den53,333            -0.6909     0.7615 112.0677  -0.907  0.36621
seas2018:den53,333           -1.6109     0.7803 112.0677  -2.064  0.04129 *
fertRDFU:seas2018:den53,333   0.3899     1.1038 112.0990   0.353  0.72461
fertWOF:seas2018:den53,333    0.8609     1.1035 112.0677   0.780  0.43696

Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1